# Table printing only when <table> tags outside of php tags

Tags: php

From everywhere I look and research it seems possible to also put the  tags within your php code, but for some reason only when my  tag is outside of php it works. I can't seem to figure out the issue with it. The reason I am trying to print inside is because I am trying to create a nested for loop. Currently I commented out the table tags outside of the php and have them printed in the php code. This currently does not work. Here is my code and thank you again.

```
<?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>User selection page</title>
    </head>

    <!-- <table border="1px"> -->
    <!-- <tbody> -->
    <?php
        /*
        Version 1.1: Instead of printing the teams in different cells we are going to print the 
        games in one row and we select the game itself to see if an upset will occur.
        */


        require_once('Conference.php');         
        $loadGameClass = new Conference();
        $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array("(1)Gonzaga vs (16)Southern U", "(8)Pittsburgh vs (9)Wichita St", "(5)Wisconsin vs (12)Ole Miss", "(4)Kansas st vs (13)Boise St", "(6)Arizona vs (11)Belmont", "(3)New Mexico vs (14) Harvard", "(7)Notre Dame vs (10)Iowa St", "(2)Ohio St vs (15) Iona"));
        $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();

        echo "<table border="1">";

        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
        {
        $highSeed = $teams[$i];
        //$lowSeed = $teams[((2*8)-1)-$i];
        echo "<tr><td>$highSeed</td>"; //<td>$lowSeed</td></tr>
        }

        echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <!-- </tbody> -->
    <!-- </table> -->

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is

```
echo "<table border="1">";
```

it should be

```
echo '<table border="1">';
```

then

```
echo "<tr><td>$highSeed</td>";
```

better way is

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$highSeed.'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: I did last time to the table tags and not the tr or td tags so that could have been the problem! Thank you for clearing up that issue!

Comment: Yes its better to seperate the html and php and I prefer to concatenate as I did in the answer.